# Ruby multiple group_by or map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I searched quite a lot but can't my head around this one.

I have a model which is related to three other models. Let's call it cities. Cities do have a continent, a country and region.

When I select some cities I want to get back an OrderedHash or an array which looks like this:

```
{ 'Continent 1' => {'Country 1' => { 'Region 1' => { 'City 1', 'City 2' }}}, 'Continent 2' ...}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What's the problem with just grouping by region and then stuffing all the regions into the appropriate hash?

Comment: Why are you wanting to translate ActiveRecord model instances that appropriately model this data into a hash that poorly represents the data and lacks functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just group by region:

```
cities_by_region = City.all(:group => :region)

# set up an automatic 3-level hash...
result = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = {}}}

cities_by_region.each do |region, cities|
  country = region.country
  result[country.continent.name][country.name][region.name] = cities
end
```

Note that this doesn't employ sorting, but it can be easily adapted to do. Keep in mind that the insertion order of hashes is only retained in Ruby 1.9+.